# Jelastic giving 502 on a nodejs application

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, jelastic

I'm running a nuxt (running on node engine) website on a simple jelastic environment made of a load-balancer (nginx) and 2 nodejs container. I'm using pm2 as a process manager.

Nuxt is listening to its own ip and port 8080. (as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68073052/nuxt-application-unavailable-on-jelastic-cloud)).
When I try to access my website I get a 502 code.

The strange thing is that it used to work, I've tried reverting my project to older working version and nothing works.
If i do a curl to the ip address and port used by nuxt I get back my correct HTML, which indicates to me that it's not an issue with Nuxt anyway.

Jelastic states that it redirects traffic from port 8080 to port 80. I don't know what to and am a bit lost.

What should I check ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As for the described situation - we've checked the nuxt application deployment on the Jelastic NodeJS node and all seems to work fine.

Please check the next possible issues:

1. Check if the hostname in the application config is not 'localhost' but '0.0.0.0' (check if it was not erased during the downgrade), details via the [link](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-server)
2. Check if the JELASTIC_EXPOSE variable is not set to '0', 'DISABLED' or 'FALSE'  - in such a case the auto-redirect will not work (more details on auto-redirect [here](https://docs.jelastic.com/container-ports/#ports-auto-redirect))
3. Try to set the 'JELASTIC_EXPOSE' variable to the exact value 8080 (or another port that is actually listening by your application)